# 'CLOSED' Get HTML code from a php webpage into string in android

Tags: php, android, string, http

Note ** This is not a duplicate question ,it is unlike getting HTML code from html page

I have tried all the codes posted on this site that are used to get HTML code from a page into a string in android.But from all of the codes I've tried , non worked on a url of **PHP** webpage, for example (http://www.jonasweb.net/samples.php) . How can I do that ?

A sample code to get HTML source as string:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

String html = "";
InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    str.append(line);
}
in.close();
html = str.toString();
```

Comment: Hmm, I have a copy of the latest Win8.1, Could you give me the source code for that?

Comment: Fixed typo , I mean HTML code of a PHP webpage

Comment: Down voters  recheck the question

Comment: Whatever the script like php/C/Java/Python the server use, they will all return a html code back (for web page), Everything is same with getting a HTML page. Just change the URL

Comment: Regular server software like apache just read the html file, add some header, then output. A php handler for a webpage read the php source code, execute it, generate the HTML output. The output are ALL the same, whatever how the server generate the output

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access PHP source code, that would be like giving Jimmy Saville the key to an un-guarded orphanage. There are so many secure things, like database connections that are stored in PHP source, It just isn't happening.

Comment: I mean HTML code of a PHP webpage , recheck the updated question

Comment: @AndroidDivalopaRRR I don't work with android (as much as I would love to), all I saw was accessing PHP code, sorry I am of no more help.

Comment: @AndroidDivalopaRRR What down-vote, You need 125Rep to down-vote, so It couldn't be me.